# Probability of miscommunication (bits)

Tags: probability

I am struggling with the following problem from Blitzstein-Introduction to Probability:

Alice is trying to communicate with Bob by sending a message across a channel.

a). First she sends only one bit with equal probabilities. If she sends a 0 there is a 5% chance of an error and Bob receives 1. If she sends a 1 the error is 10% and Bob gets a 0. Given Bob got a 1 what is the probability that Alice sent a 1?

Let $A$ the event that a 1 was sent, $B$ a 1 was received, $E$ error occured while sending a 1.
I need to find $P(A|B)$ and this is equal to $\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$ and 
$P(B)=0.05*1/2+0.9*1/2=0.47$ and I get $P(A|B)=0.9*0.5/0.47=0.95$.

I am having problems at the second part of the problem which is:

b). They decide to use repetition code. She sends 000 to convey a 0 and 111 to convey a 1. Bob will decode the message by going with what the majority of the bits were. Given Bob receives 110 what is the probability that Alice sent a 1?

Let R=received, S=sent. I am thinking to condition on $P(S=111|R=110)=\frac{P(R=110|S=111)*P(S=111)}{P(R=110)}$. Now $P(S=111)$ is 1/2 as is the probability of sending a 1.

$P(R=110|S=111)=0.9^2*0.1$ because 1 error occurred in the last bit (1 instead of 0). Using data from part a), the errors for each bit are independent (is this correct?)

$P(R=110)=P(R=110|S=111)P(S=111)+P(R=110|S=000)P(S=000)=0.9^2*0.1*1/2+0.05^2*0.95*1/2=0.041$

Then, my solution is $P(S=111|R=110)=0.04/0.041=0.97$. The answer looks ok numerically but is my reasoning correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes your logic is correct, I didn't check the numerics. You can assume the channel uses are independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. Whether or not the errors are independent should typically not be assumed, but since the problem is unsolvable if the errors are dependent I think it's safe to assume they are independent. (If the errors are dependent you have no way of knowing how they are dependent.) So $P(R=110 \mid S=111)=0.9^2 * 0.1$ just as you said.

It seems that was your main question because of the rest of the probabilities follow from the errors being independent. Your combinatorial reasoning is good. The chance of error in one location is $0.9^2 * 0.1$ if $111$ was sent and the chance of error in one location is $0.5^2 * 0.95$ if $000$ was sent.

So if assurances are what you're looking for let me say this: You are right.

Comment: Yes, my problem was on independence and (more important) combinatoric reasoning. I am trying to build intuition on combinatorics.I struggled and I actually reached this form while trying to write it here. Thank you!